# How to properly use XML file as datasource in node js application

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, express

Im developing a web application that uses XML files as datasource. I dont have a database and all the data are stored in XML files. My application is based on nodejs and express and Im not experienced with this architecture. I'm looking for a best practice/suggestion to read data from this XML file and fit everything in an MVC architecture. More specifically Is there a way to have a model where, instead of connecting to a db, I can read the data from an XML file and pass back to controller? (I only need to read these xml files and never modify them)

Comment: This is probably going to get flagged.   But, I use XML2JS https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js

Comment: it looks interesting to convert xml to json...but how can I build a model that uses this json?

Comment: Follow the "Simple as pie usage" example, reading in one of the files, view the result in the console.log.  You will see the JSON result of your xml layout.  You can simply pass that json back to your controller or just parts of it depending on your requirement.    Hard to know since I dont really know what you mean by controller.  Can you elaborate more on your framework or design?